# Migrationscript with for MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb

i need help for migrationscript for a mongodb collection.

This is a example how it looks like and I wanna update it that the Error field should be an array in the future.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "632a11c91f786f7d86d7633a"
    },
    "List": [
      {
        "Name": "WithError",
        "Error": "duplicate"
      },
      {
        "Name": "WithOutError"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is a example how it should look like:

```
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "632a11c91f786f7d86d7633a"
  },
  "List": [
    {
      "Name": "WithError",
      "Error": ["duplicate"]
    },
    {
      "Name": "WithOutError"
    }
  ]
}
```

My plan is to use updateMany, but I need help for the filter and how to do the update.

Kind Regards and Thx for the help

Comment: Interesting question. Unfortunately trying `db.b.updateMany(
    { "List.Name": "WithError" }, 
    { "$set": { "List.$.Error": [ "$List.$.Error" ] } }
)` sets the "Error" field to an array with the literal `"$List.$.Error"` rather than retrieving the Error field from the existing array element... hoping someone else can take this a step farther.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation pipeline within `updateMany`, something like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "List": {
        $map: {
          input: "$List",
          as: "element",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$$element.Error",
                  false
                ]
              },
              then: {
                Name: "$$element.Name",
                Error: [
                  "$$element.Error"
                ]
              },
              else: "$$element"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xel0fb--fgG).
With `updateMany` the query will be:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "List": {
        $map: {
          input: "$List",
          as: "element",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$$element.Error",
                  false
                ]
              },
              then: {
                Name: "$$element.Name",
                Error: [
                  "$$element.Error"
                ]
              },
              else: "$$element"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

To check for string type, you can try this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "List": {
        $map: {
          input: "$List",
          as: "element",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    $toBool: "$$element.Error"
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "string",
                      {
                        $type: "$$element.Error"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: {
                Name: "$$element.Name",
                Error: [
                  "$$element.Error"
                ]
              },
              else: "$$element"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HyV2GCDEMFQ).

Comment: I tried so i wanna have the following changes:
- all documents in the collection should be updated. So I removed the filter: "List.Name": "WithError"
- to check if we wanna update I just want to use the $exists expression, but this did not work like: ... $cond: { if: { $exists: [ "Error", true ]},

Comment: Updated the answer, `$exists` is not available within aggregation pipeline. You should use `$ifNull` @MarkusBenz

Comment: Thx this is working, but to call this update often I need to check if Error is off type string, how can I do this?

Comment: Added another query in the answer.